# Select Record with Maximum Creation Date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Let us say that I have a database table with the following two records:

```
CACHE_ID  BUSINESS_DATE  CREATED_DATE
1183      13-09-06       13-09-19 16:38:59.336000000
1169      13-09-06       13-09-24 17:19:05.762000000
1152      13-09-06       13-09-17 14:18:59.336000000
1173      13-09-05       13-09-19 15:48:59.136000000
1139      13-09-05       13-09-24 12:59:05.263000000
1152      13-09-05       13-09-27 13:28:59.332000000
```

I need to write a query that will return the CACHE_ID for the record which has the most recent CREATED_DATE.

I am having trouble crafting such a query.  I can do a GROUP BY based on BUSINESS_DATE and get the MAX(CREATED_DATE)...of course, I won't have the CACHE_ID of the record.

Could someone help with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not positive on oracle syntax, but use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function:

```
SELECT BUSINESS_DATE, CACHE_ID
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY BUSINESS_DATE ORDER BY CREATED_DATE DESC) RN
      FROM YourTable t
     )sub
WHERE RN = 1
```

The `ROW_NUMBER()` function assigns a number to each row. `PARTITION BY` is optional, but used to start the numbering over for each value in that group,  ie: if you `PARTITION BY BUSINESS_DATE`  then for each unique BUSINESS_DATE value the numbering would start over at 1.  `ORDER BY` of course is used to define how the counting should go, and is required in the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

Comment: This answer looks promising.  I'll give it a try.  Thanks.

Comment: This solution works.  I've modified the query to work with Oracle.

Comment: I tried to edit the comment but the edit seems to have been rejected.  Conceptually this will work, but they syntax won't work on Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 1):

You want to group on business date, and get the CACHE_ID with the most current created date?  Use something like this:

```
select yt.CACHE_ID, yt.BUSINESS_DATE, yt.CREATED_DATE
from YourTable yt
where yt.CREATED_DATE = (select max(yt1.CREATED_DATE)
                           from YourTable yt1
                          where yt1.BUSINESS_DATE = yt.BUSINESS_DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the exact syntax, but conceptually, can't you just sort by CREATED_DATE descending and take the first one?

Comment: I don't want just the first record from the entire table.  I guess the example is bad.  I can have multiple records for the same business date.  For each business date, I need the most recently created record.  I'll update the example.

Answer (score 0):

Across all records -

```
select top 1 CACHE_ID from YourTable order by CREATED_DATE desc
```

For each BUSINESS_DATE -

```
select distinct 
a.BUSINESS_DATE,
(
    select top 1 b.CACHE_ID 
    from YourTable b where a.BUSINESS_DATE = b.BUSINESS_DATE
    order by b.CREATED_DATE desc
) as Last_CREATED_DATE
from YourTable a
```

Comment: TOP isn't a valid operator in Oracle.  Also, I don't want the maximum cache id.  I want the most recent cache id, indicated by the CREATED_DATE.